# PermissionError: [WinError 32]

Tags: python

I'm studying python in school now and I tried to run the code provided by professor. However, this is the biggest issue so far I cannot figure out.
I have downloaded rpy2 and when I try to install R packages (e.g. shiny)
it shows PermissionError: [WinError 32]. How do I fix it?

```
%pylab inline
import os
from ipypublish import nb_setup
%load_ext rpy2.ipython

%%R
install.packages("shiny")
```

I got this error message:

> PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process:  'C:\Users\-\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpa7_m8p_n\Rplots001.png'

Comment: Close the file: `C:\Users\-\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpa7_m8p_n\Rplots001.png` it's open and in use.

Comment: Try to restart your computer first :)

Comment: The file is not open. I've tried to delete it but it just keeps pop up in the Temp file.